# Getting list of files in a folder on SharePoint 2010 using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

So I need to be able to retrieve the name of the files in a folder on SharePoint 2010 so I can build the URL to that pdf. I don't have SharePoint on the server that I am developing on and can not develop on the server that does. I got the SharePoint client ddls but I can't seem to get my intranet webpage to communicate with SharePoint. If someone can just point me in the right direction, that would be great.

here's one of my attempts, pretty sure it's not right

```
    ClientContext cc = new ClientContext("Urlgoeshere");
    List partsList = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Folder Name");
    CamlQuery camlQueryPartsList = new CamlQuery();
    cc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password", "domain");
    camlQueryPartsList.ViewXml =
      @"<View>
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <BeginsWith>
          <FieldRef Name='CustomerSpecs' />
          <Value Type='Text'></Value>
        </BeginsWith>
      </Where>
    </Query>
  </View>";
    partsList.GetItems(camlQueryPartsList);
    cc.Load(partsList);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get a error saying Cannot contact site at the specified URL urlgoeshere
or if I add in credentials it says unauthorized but I have permission so not sure why I get that

Comment: And what problems are you having connecting to the site?  What code are you executing?  What happens when you execute it?

Comment: Is "URLGoesHere" the actual URL of your site?  Is it the correct URL of your site?

Comment: lol no, i put that there instead of the my company's website